# Find() using timestamp

Tags: mongodb, date, timestamp, mongodb-query

I'm trying to query a MongoDB collection to find an alarm between two dates. The problem is that the date is a timestamp. My code is:

```
rs.slaveOk();
print("mac;inicio;fin;valor_inicial;valor_actual");
db.alarmas.find(
{   
   timestamp_inicio_alarma:
        {
            $gt: ISODate("2018-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            $lt: ISODate("2018-02-28T23:59:59.000Z")
        },
        valor_inicial: {$eq: 'ON: AC Line Fail'},
        estado_alarma: {$eq: 'SOLUCIONADA'}
        }
   ).forEach(function(alarmas){
        print(alarmas.mac+";"+alarmas.timestamp_inicio_alarma+";"+alarmas.timestamp_fin_alarma+";"+alarmas.valor_inicial+";"+alarmas.valor_actual);
   }
);
```

The data format is:

[image]

The problem is it's not finding anything. How can I query right?

Thank you very much. MongoDB it's a tool for me, I'm not a programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your screenshot `timestamp_inicio_alarma` is persisted as `Int64` not `Date`. I'm guessing the value in `timestamp_inicio_alarma` is the epoch seconds.

So, you are trying to apply a date based query against a document attribute which contains a number **not** a date. This is why your query is not matching anything.

The following query would match the document shown in your screenshot ...

```
db.alarmas.find({ 
    timestamp_inicio_alarma: { $gt: 1457029620, $lt: 1457029640}
})
```

... but, of course, that's difficult to understand (who knows what `1457029620` means, in terms of a date ;).

So, either:

- Your model changes; to persist `timestamp_inicio_alarma` as a date. If so, then the way you expressed the query in your question would be valid.
- Your query changes; to express the dates as seconds since the epoch (assuming that's the vaule in `timestamp_inicio_alarma`). For example:

  ```
  var start = ISODate("2018-02-01T00:00:00.000Z").getTime() / 1000;
  var end = ISODate("2018-02-28T23:59:59.000Z").getTime() / 1000;

  db.alarmas.find({ 
      timestamp_inicio_alarma: { $gt: start, $lt: end}
  })
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find any document by numeric field (timestamp) you can pass this number to Date

```
db.alarmas.find({
  timestamp_inicio_alarma: { 
    $gt: new Date(start),
    $lt: new Date(end) 
  }
})
```

Where start and end are timestamp example: 1601949824094